# To extract a string based on some specific characters

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, excel-2010, trim

I have values in rows like below:

```
Https://abc/uvw/xyz
Https://def/klm/qew/asdas
Https://ghi/sdk/asda/as/aa/
Https://jkl/asd/vcx/asdsss/ssss/
```

Now i want the result to be like below

```
Https://abc/uvw/xyz
Https://def/klm/qew
Https://ghi/sdk/asda
Https://jkl/asd/vcx
```

So how to take result by skipping / for up to some count or is there any other way to get this done in excel. Is there any way to skip result of the RIGHT when it Finds 4 '/' in string?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `SUBSTITUTE` to replace the nth `/` (in this case 5th) to a unique character and perform a `LEFT` based on that unique character obtained from `FIND`. I'll take `CHAR(1)` as the unique character:

```
=LEFT(A1,IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),5))-1,LEN(A1)))
```

[image]

Another option would be to split on `/` using Text to Columns under the Data tab and join back only the columns you need.

Comment: in some cases it is failing...i dont know why...but in most of the rows it is working fine.

Comment: @AdarshAwasthi Care to share the cases where it is failing? That would give me a better idea as to why it might be failing.

Comment: same data is there in every row...but sometimes it is returning results till 6 '/' and sometimes till 5 '/' .so not following exact order.

Comment: @AdarshAwasthi Can you share any snapshots?

Comment: A snapshot is unlikely to help. I suspect that a unicode fraction slash (8260) or division slash (8275) is being used.

Comment: @user11121185 what is the solution in that case?

Comment: @AdarshAwasthi They look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/256GM.png) (at least under Calibri font). You could do a Find&Replace to replace all of them with a regular forward slash and then use the formula I proposed.